# Pass single PHP value from ACF Repeater Field

Tags: javascript, php, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I have a page for team members of a company. The team members are rendered with an ACF repeater that has fields for Name, Job Title, and Biography. On the page I would like to render just their Name, and Job Title. If you were to click on a team member, that would open a modal that would render that team members biography.

I have this working, but my approach adds the Biography field to the DOM for each team member, hides it, and passes it into the modal on click. I am wondering if it is possible to pass the Biography field into the modal without having to render the text in the DOM initially and hiding it?

Below is my current code:

```php
<!-- acf repeater -->
<?php if( have_rows('team_member') ): ?>
    <?php while( have_rows('team_member') ): the_row();
        $name = get_sub_field('name');
        $job_title = get_sub_field('job_title');
        $biography = get_sub_field('biography');

    ?>
        <div class="team-member">
            <div>
                <?php echo $name ?>
            </div>
            <div>
                <?php echo $job_title ?>
            </div>
            <div class="biography" style="display: none;">
                <?php echo $biography ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <!-- modal -->
    <div class="modal">
        modal
        <div class="modal-biography">

        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

```js
<!-- javascript -->
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.team-member').on('click', function() {
        var modalBiography = $(this).find('.biography').text();
        $('.modal-biography').text(modalBiography);
    })
});
```

Comment: You could inline a function call on the `.team-member` and set the argument in PHP... but this is kind of an ugly way to do things. (`<button onclick="setModal(<?php echo $biography ?>)">` ... and write a corresponding function in javascript, `function setModal(modalBiography) {/* Do stuff here */}`)

You could also render a different `modal` element in the dom for each `team_member` block, and then in the event listener in javascript, have it show the corresponding modal element and hide the rest.

Honestly the way you're doing it is okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to display the bio `div`, I'd suggest just putting it into a `data-bio` attribute:

```
<div class="team-member" data-bio="<?php echo $biography; ?>">
    <div><?php echo $name; ?></div>
    <div><?php echo $job_title; ?></div>
</div>
```

then tweak js a bit to pull this `data-bio` instead:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.team-member').on('click', function() {
        var modalBiography = $(this).data('bio');
        $('.modal-biography').text(modalBiography);
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This is working well for me.